# Why isn't my Luminance edit saved in Camera Raw?

Tags: adobe-camera-raw

I recently edited some features such as color, contrast, temperature, lens correction, and etc. and also luminance to reduce the noise of a picture in Camera Raw. But when I save that edited picture in any format (such as DNG, TIFF, JPG) all the new settings remains but luminance and it's not as clear as I see in Camera Raw. What is the problem and what should I do about it?

I attached the preview in Camera Raw and a JPG saved of that edited file.

[image: Preview in Camera Raw]
Preview in Camera Raw

[image: How it saves without noise reduction settings]
How it saves without noise reduction settings

Comment: Maybe the changes have to do with monitor calibration? In Windows calibration must be supported by the app.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I think the same is happening to me! :-)
Thanks

Comment: Clarify that you mean the “luminance noise reduction slider”, not exposure.

Answer (score 1):

The luminance of these pictures seem pretty similar to me. Pulling down the shadows will not help in reducing noise in the "lighter" parts of the image. Use the noise control sliders.

You can't judge noise in the ACR preview unless you view it at 100%.

Comment: thank you for your answer. as you said I zoomed in 100% and the result was strange. both pictures were similar! but if you open these two pictures that I attached here you will get my point. because the preview image in Camera Raw is smoother than the JPG saved of that image. that is obvious. I want my saved image exactly looks like my preview in Camera Raw. at least not in details. and about the using noise control slider I didn't get your point. because I exactly used them! and the difference between these two images is related to the luminance feature I think.

Comment: I wonder if its a colour profile issue?

Comment: I think by “luminance” the OP means the luminance noise reduction slider, nothing to do with the exposure.